# Android webview issues in Xamarin. pageYOffset, window.innerHeight, scroll

Tags: javascript, webview, xamarin, android-webview

I'm debugging a WebView in Android 4.4.2 in a Xamarin app.
The WebView is "Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0".
My Javascript code isn't running well there since several properties have false values.
I get pageYOffset as 0 even after scroll, the "scroll" event won't even fire and window.innerHeight returns the total height of the DOC rather than the visible pixel dependant height.
I have no control over the native code, can modify the script only.
Is this a Xamarin issue? A WebView issue?
Is this somehow can be resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether Xamarin ships its own WebView or uses the one from the system. WebView version 30 is kind of old. I would try on more recent Android versions first.

Comment: Hi,
I have no control over the selected webview since it runs by the app.
I'm pretty sure that the app uses the default Android stacked webview.

Comment: I know, what I'm suggesting is to try the same app on a different mobile device that uses a more recent version of Android and hence, WebView.

Comment: And another thing, this is the formal WebView Android 4.4 version according to this DOC:
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: So it's not a matter of device but rather a matter of the Android version (KitKat).
This was tested on LG G2 and Nexus 5.

Comment: BTW, I tested in Phonegap as well and it works OK there.
Could me the way that Xamarin initialize the webview or a Xamarin issue.
They both use the same webview version.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I don't know much about Xamarin, though.

Comment: Same here :)
Well, I didn't get any responses from their forums as well :(